# Woocommerce cart fees

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to add to an existing fee, but when I use:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
    function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
        global $woocommerce;
        $cartfee = $woocommerce->cart->get_fees();
        $stripefee = 0.015;
        $perorder = 0.20;
        $surcharge1 = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $stripefee;
        $bookingfee = $surcharge1 + $perorder + $cartfee;
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Booking Fee', $bookingfee, true, '' );
    }
```

There is already a Booking Fee of 0.30 that displays fine on the cart, when I add the above it does the $surcharge1 + $perorder but the $cartfee is empty. It doesn't seem to read the existing fee. The Booking fee is from a plugin that I can set a % per product.

Any help to point me in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What's kind of value $woocommerce->cart->get_fees() this one returns (your $cartfee)? Seems like it should be an array. Did you check for an empty array?

Comment: I'm new to this, so sorry not sure. I'm trying to find a way to read the cart fees, and then add to it and save back.

Comment: get_fees() returns an array. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-surcharge-to-cart-and-checkout-uses-fees-api/ did you check this article? Maybe you can find something useful there

Comment: Btw, there is interesting info here http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartadd_fee/ . Seems like you fail in this because only 1 fee with such name ('Booking Fee') can exist - no duplicates. First, try not to use get_fees(), or get sum of array values properly. And second, try to add_fee() with name parameter not matching existing fee. You can make your own 'Booking fee' from scratch, or (bad idea, btw), at least modify plugin in place where 'Booking Fee' fee is added.

Comment: I seem to be able to add a new fee, I just cannot seem to read the existing ones. I have tried using
        $cartfees = $woocommerce->cart->get_fees();
        foreach ($cartfees as $cartfee) {
and then adding the fee with $cartfee['amount']; Still does not show the amount.

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html maybe this helps, don't know. get_fee_total() isn't what you are looking for? Sorry, have no woocommerce installed to try out.

Comment: Try please to use not Booking Fee name (so you will not rewrite existing fee), rename your fee with another name. Just for a test. Maybe you rewrite existing Booking Fee and that's why it's not working. And as I wrote above, check out documentation for another function to get fees amount :)